# Unablen to change Laravel Fortify CreateNewUser Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-fortify

I just installed fortify in a new project am working and would like to change the validation rules. Changing the is not actually the problem, the problem is after i have changed the validation errors, am still getting the default validation errors for name,email and password whereas i have totally removed name field from the validation rules.

**Here is my CreateNewUser validation Code**

```php
Validator::make($input, [
    'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'email',
        'max:255',
        Rule::unique(User::class),
    ],
    'phone_number' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'max:20',
        Rule::unique(User::class),
    ],
    'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
])->validate();
```

and when i make a request to **/register route** i get:

```
"name":["The name field is required."],"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}
```

i have also ran `php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan view:clear`, `php artisan config:clear` but am still getting the same result

Comment: Can you show how you changed validation errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a close look at `php artisan route:list`, i discovered that the **register** route is connected to `App\Http\Auth\RegisterController`.
[image]
Which may be as a result of **laravel ui**  i installed. so, i have to uninstall it or use switch over to using laravel ui RegisterController. i hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your field name changes on your user table and re-run the migrations.  Also, update the new fields in the user model as well as your input fields in your form.